# (LikesController#create) expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0 ,Please teach me a hint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm biginer.
I studied Rspec.

I made an implementation that allowed me to do good on my posts.

But on the browser I do the expected move, but the test does not pass.

The destroy action goes through the test, but the create action does not pass the test.

My error is

```
Failure/Error: expect { post :create, format: :js, params: { post_id: post1.id, id: like.id } }.to change(Like, :count).by(1)
       expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
```

My code is

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe LikesController, type: :controller do
  let!(:user) { create(:user) }
  let!(:post1) { create(:post, user: user) }
  let!(:like) { create(:like, user_id: user.id, post_id: post1.id) }

  describe "#create" do
    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    it "response Ajex" do
      post :create, format: :js, params: { post_id: post1.id, id: like.id }
      expect(response.content_type).to eq 'text/javascript'
    end

    it "success like function" do
      expect { post :create, format: :js, params: { post_id: post1.id, id: like.id } }.to change(Like, :count).by(1)
    end
  end

  describe "#destroy" do
    before do
      sign_in user
    end

    it "response Ajex" do
      delete :destroy, format: :js, params: { post_id: post1.id, user_id: user.id, id: like.id }
      expect(response.content_type).to eq 'text/javascript'
    end

    it "delete like function" do
      expect { delete :destroy, format: :js, params: { post_id: post1.id, user_id: user.id, id: like.id } }.to change(Like, :count).by(-1)
    end
  end
end
```

likes_controller.rb

```
 class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @like =
current_user.likes.find_or_create_by(post_id:params[:post_id])
    @likes = Like.where(post_id: params[:post_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end

  def destroy
    like = current_user.likes.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id])
    like.destroy
    @likes = Like.where(post_id: params[:post_id])
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

I cannot solove this problem.
Please teach me a hint.

Comment: It would be a good idea to back up a bit and test your models with the rails console.  I'd start up the console and manually create instances of your model classes, relate them, etc and see if it they are behaving correctly.  [related video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CDSRGdH7Lnk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an error in your code somewhere, most likely, which is why the `Like` count fails to increment. First, I'd try and figure out why it isn't incrementing. Since you asked for a hint, here's one way you can split out the "success like function" block:

```
context "valid" do
  before do
    post :create, format: :js, params: { post_id: post1.id, id: like.id }
  end

  it "success" do
    # You can inject a binding.pry here if needed
    expect(response.status).to eq(200)
  end

  it "response" do
    # You can inject a `binding.pry` here if needed
    # You can also inspect the `response.body` with puts if needed
    expect(JSON.parse(response.body)).to include(
      # You would modify this to match the shape of your response
      post: a_hash_including(
        like: like.id
      )
    )
  end
end
```

You'll want to install `pry-rails` and `pry-byebug` gems (for inspecting).

The reason behind splitting them up is it makes it easier to determine the issue (you can have a valid response code but not the expected result, for example). This comes with some caveats (it will make for slower tests) but in this example it will make it easier to determine why your `post` is failing.

The snippet above should help you debug the error; once you fix it you can revert back to your previous method of checking.

Comment: `JSON::ParserError:
       765: unexpected token at '$("#like-1").html("    <form class=\"button_to\" method=\"post\" action=\"/posts/1/likes/1\" data-remote=\"true\"><input type=\"hidden\" name=\"_method\" value=\"delete\" /><button type=\"submit\"> \n      <img src=\"/assets/icon_red_heart-359c7031992df6009985e277af10a7c177411dbb5d041a98d18c69a302a8d2ae.png\" />\n      <span>\n        1\n      <\/span>\n<\/button><\/form>");'`

Comment: @kodai, it looks like the response body is a partial HTML, so you don't need the JSON.parse piece that I posted. However, looking at your code a 2nd time I think it's failing to create because you used the `let!` syntax for your `like`, so when it gets to your controller that's already created (so it finds it because find_or_create_by). Remove the ! And re run it and it should be able to create. The deconstruction above might hopefully be useful I'm the future